# C# Normalize (like a vector)

Tags: c#, vector, normalize

Code in my moving object:

```
ObjectX.Location.Add(Velocity * Utils.GetMoveDir(start, destination));
```

Utility function:

```
public static PointF GetMoveDir(PointF start, PointF destination)
{
    PointF substraction = destination.SubStract(start);

    if (substraction == PointF.Empty) // If-statement is needed because normalizing a zero value results in a NaN value
         return PointF.Empty;
    else return substraction.Normalize(); // I need something for this
}
```

The extension I can't get to work:

```
public static PointF Normalize(this PointF A)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // How do I solve this to make it like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.normalize.aspx
}
```

Note that I do NOT use the XNA framework.

Comment: Is `PointF` actually `System.Drawing.PointF` or something else? Above mentioned `PointF` does not have `SubStract` non-static method, but it does have `Subtract` static one.

Comment: Sorry I forgot  to mention, it is an extension method of mine on PointF. But it is a real PointF as in System.Drawing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static PointF Normalize(this PointF A)
{
    float distance = Math.Sqrt(A.X * A.X + A.Y * A.Y);
    return new PointF(A.X / distance, A.Y / distance);
}
```

Also see the first paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) to learn what a normalized vector (unit vector) is and how you can calculate it.

Comment: Works like a charm (both answers work btw). Just note that you have to add a float-cast to make it compile: (float)Math.Sqrt(..);

Answer (score 4):

```
public static PointF Normalize(this PointF A)
{
    float length = Math.Sqrt( A.X*A.X + A.Y*A.Y);
    return new PointF( A.X/length, A.Y/length);
}
```